# Chromium - Share Browser Tabs?

Tags: chrome, tabs

Is there a way that I could share the browser tabs from one computer onto another? Ideally, I'd like to close my browser on my desktop, use my laptop and they'd be there. I then like to close Chromium on my Laptop and restore it from my Desktop ad nauseum.

I've a feeling the use of ownCloud could be involved. I don't want to use someone else's servers. I'm unsure of the issues caused if both browsers were opened at the same time.

I guess that the .config/chromium folder should be shared. I'm wondering what the minimum amount of data I could share would be.

Answer (score 0):

You could Bookmark each of the tabs.
Create a folder for them called "Restore Tabs" or something similar.
The Bookmarks and folder will sync across the two computers.
Then open the folder, RIGHT-click on it and choose "Open all bookmarks".